# Managed Metadata Column Visibility

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, permissions, column, managed-metadata

Having an issue where tags in managed metadata columns will not display in DispForm.aspx for a non-admin user, but display normally for admins. I have tried adding "NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users" with "read" access to the library, but this has not given non-admin users the visibility they need.

The strange thing is, when a non-admin user edits the properties of a single document, in the EditForm.aspx, the metadata tags are visible.

Has anyone experienced this before?